# PhantomJS Python Hangs?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

For some reason in the middle of my script PhantomJS just hangs: 
**Phantomjs version = 1.9.8**
[INFO  - 2015-10-08T16:34:08.473Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: 65e82940-6dda-11e5-8a19-53533527191c, and so on....

What is the reason for this and what is the best solution? Also can someone explain if using implicit / explicit waits would fix this problem?  I was reading about it and dont seem to grasp that concept.  Somewhere in this code chunk:

```
tree = etree.HTML(driver.page_source)
time.sleep(3)
nhsfield1 = tree.xpath('//h1//text()')[0].strip().split()[-3] + " " +    tree.xpath('//h1//text()')[0].strip().split()[-2]
time.sleep(3)
print "Scraping elements Scout"
try:
    print "Field2"
    nhsfield2 = tree.xpath('//div[@class="breadcrumbs"]//text()')[-1].strip()   [1:].strip()
except Exception as e:
    print "error nhsfield2"
    nhsfield2 = ""
    print e
print "Field3"
nhsfield3 = tree.xpath('//h1//text()')[0].strip().split(":")[-1].strip()
driver.find_element_by_id("ui-id-3").click()
time.sleep(2)
```

right after scraping elements scout it hangs?

Comment: You say *"in the middle of my script PhantomJS just hangs"*, but where exactly is that in your code? There is not enough information to diagnose your problem.